# Use tinyalsa from ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, libraries

I'm writing an app that should use functions from tinyalsa through ndk, I just want to call functions defined by tinyalsa like pcm_open() from my native functions implementations.

I have tried following the documentation about using prebuilt libraries in Android/ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html but I can't get it working.

Could you please tell how could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give details about what you tried? Can you show your Android.mk file?

Comment: I could do it, and posted the answer, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could do it, the process is the next:

1. Copy tinyalsa.so to ~/Android/ndk/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib
2. Copy asoundlib.h to ~/Android/ndk/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include

   Platform-18 is the one I'm using. It can be specified in **Application.mk** with the line

   ```
   APP_PLATFORM := android-18
   ```
3. After adding it to the ndk platform include it in the file where the native functions are implemented

   ```
   #include <asoundlib.h>
   ```
4. Tell the compiler that we are going to need this library. In **Android.mk**

   ```
   LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ltinyalsa
   ```

This worked for me :)

Comment: `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := tinyalsa` works for me than `LOCAL_LDLIBS`

Comment: Are you sure that this will work for all devices? According https://source.android.com/devices/audio/ at Kernel level instead `ALSA` can be used `OSS` or custom module

Comment: Where do you get the file `tinyalsa.so`? (I know I should be able to compile it by download the source, but wouldn't that `.so` file be built for an x86 architecture, whereas my android device runs on ARM?)